# Not able to connect to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an EC2 instance with proper inbound rules but still, I'm not able to connect to an EC2 instance using terminal or EC2 instance connect.

**Security group inbound rules:**

[image: security group inbound rules]

**Terminal screenshot:**

[image: terminal screenshot]

**EC2 instance connect screenshot:**

[image: ec2 instance connect screenshot]

Comment: Have you _ever_ been able to connect to this Amazon EC2 instance? Are you able to connect to any other instances in the same VPC?

Answer (score 1):

Your Security Group looks good, but "Operation timed out" indicates that there is no communication to the instance.

Things to check:

- The EC2 instance has been launched in a **public subnet** (defined as a subnet with a Route Table entry pointing to an Internet Gateway)
- The **Network ACLs** are at their default "Allow All" settings (There is generally no need to change NACL settings)
- The instance is running **Linux**
- **Your network** allows outbound SSH connections (try Home vs Office vs Tethered via your phone)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue before and found that connectivity problems can have several causes. To troubleshoot this, consider the following step:

**Network connectivity:** Check your internet connection from the device you're attempting to connect with. Test accessing other websites or services to ensure connectivity is functioning properly. If you're using your office Wi-Fi network, some organizations might have restrictions that prevent connecting to external resources. In such cases, try using a different network, such as a mobile hotspot, to rule out any network-related issues.